# How do i group XML on supplier code inside orderline?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a XML input and want to translate this xml for our ERP system by a xslt file.
What i want to do is grouping on the supplier_code.
So i want 1 iorh for each supplier code with all iorr for that iorh.

XML Input:

```
<NewDataSet>
<OrderLine>
    <SUPPLIER_CODE>01</SUPPLIER_CODE>
    <ITEM_CODE>xxx</ITEM_CODE>
    <ITEM_DESCRIPTION>xxx</ITEM_DESCRIPTION>
    <ORDER_QTY>2.00</ORDER_QTY>
</OrderLine>
<OrderLine>
    <SUPPLIER_CODE>01</SUPPLIER_CODE>
    <ITEM_CODE>yyy</ITEM_CODE>
    <ITEM_DESCRIPTION>yyy</ITEM_DESCRIPTION>
    <ORDER_QTY>3.00</ORDER_QTY>
</OrderLine>
<OrderLine>
    <SUPPLIER_CODE>02</SUPPLIER_CODE>
    <ITEM_CODE>zzz</ITEM_CODE>
    <ITEM_DESCRIPTION>zzz</ITEM_DESCRIPTION>
    <ORDER_QTY>1.00</ORDER_QTY>
</OrderLine>
<OrderLine>
    <SUPPLIER_CODE>02</SUPPLIER_CODE>
    <ITEM_CODE>uuu</ITEM_CODE>
    <ITEM_DESCRIPTION>uuuu</ITEM_DESCRIPTION>
    <ORDER_QTY>2.00</ORDER_QTY>
</OrderLine>
<OrderLine>
    <SUPPLIER_CODE>03</SUPPLIER_CODE>
    <ITEM_CODE>vvv</ITEM_CODE>
    <ITEM_DESCRIPTION>vvv</ITEM_DESCRIPTION>
    <ORDER_QTY>2.00</ORDER_QTY>
</OrderLine>
```

XSLT:

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
        <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
            <xsl:template match="/">
                <DataSet>
                    <xsl:for-each select="NewDataSet/OrderLine">
                        <xsl:sort select="SUPPLIER_CODE"/>
                        <iorh>
                            <iorh.cred_num>
                                <xsl:value-of select="SUPPLIER_CODE"/>
                            </iorh.cred_num>
                            <iorr>
                                <iorr.arti_code>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="ITEM_CODE"/>
                                </iorr.arti_code>
                                <iorr.iorr_oms_1>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="ITEM_CODE"/>
                                </iorr.iorr_oms_1>
                                <iorr.iorr_oms_2>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="ITEM_DESCRIPTION"/>
                                </iorr.iorr_oms_2>
                                <iorr.iorr_order_aantal>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="ORDER_QTY"/>
                                </iorr.iorr_order_aantal>
                            </iorr>
                        </iorh>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </DataSet>
            </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML Output that i want:

```
    <DataSet>
    <iorh> //1x for every SUPPLIER_CODE
        <iorh.cred_num>
        01
        </iorh.cred_num>
    </iorh>
    <iorr>
        <iorr.arti_code>
        xxx
        </iorr.arti_code>
        <iorr.iorr_oms_1>
        xxx
        </iorr.iorr_oms_1>
        <iorr.iorr_oms_2>
        xxx
        </iorr.iorr_oms_2>
        <iorr.iorr_order_aantal>
        2.00
        </iorr.iorr_order_aantal>
    </iorr>
    <iorr>
        <iorr.arti_code>
        yyy
        </iorr.arti_code>
        <iorr.iorr_oms_1>
        yyy
        </iorr.iorr_oms_1>
        <iorr.iorr_oms_2>
        yyy
        </iorr.iorr_oms_2>
        <iorr.iorr_order_aantal>
        3.00
        </iorr.iorr_order_aantal>
    </iorr>
    <iorh> //1x for every SUPPLIER_CODE
        <iorh.cred_num>
        02
        </iorh.cred_num>
    </iorh>
    <iorr>
        <iorr.arti_code>
        vvv
        </iorr.arti_code>
        <iorr.iorr_oms_1>
        vvv
        </iorr.iorr_oms_1>
        <iorr.iorr_oms_2>
        vvv
        </iorr.iorr_oms_2>
        <iorr.iorr_order_aantal>
        2.00
        </iorr.iorr_order_aantal>
    </iorr>
    .....................................
</DataSet>
```

I now get for every new supplier code/order line a new iorh.
Can anyone tell/explain me how to do this / is it possible to do this?
Hope u understand.

Comment: You need to specify which XSLT version. Solutions to grouping problems are much easier in XSLT 2.0. If you need an XSLT 1.0 solution, search this site or look in the index of your favourite XSLT textbook for "Muenchian grouping".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `xsl:key` as reference to group by **supplier_code**.

```
<xsl:key use="SUPPLIER_CODE" match="/NewDataSet/OrderLine" name="groups"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/NewDataSet" />
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/NewDataSet">
    <DataSet>
        <xsl:for-each select="OrderLine[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('groups',SUPPLIER_CODE))]"> 
            <xsl:sort select="SUPPLIER_CODE"/>
            <iorh>
                <iorh.cred_num>
                    <xsl:value-of select="SUPPLIER_CODE"/>
                </iorh.cred_num>
                <xsl:for-each select="key('groups',SUPPLIER_CODE)">
                    <iorr>
                        <iorr.arti_code>
                            <xsl:value-of select="ITEM_CODE"/>
                        </iorr.arti_code>
                        <iorr.iorr_oms_1>
                            <xsl:value-of select="ITEM_CODE"/>
                        </iorr.iorr_oms_1>
                        <iorr.iorr_oms_2>
                            <xsl:value-of select="ITEM_DESCRIPTION"/>
                        </iorr.iorr_oms_2>
                        <iorr.iorr_order_aantal>
                            <xsl:value-of select="ORDER_QTY"/>
                        </iorr.iorr_order_aantal>
                    </iorr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </iorh>
        </xsl:for-each>
    <DataSet>
</xsl:template>
```